# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style') Getting this error for the code

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations

I tried this block of code and got the Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style'). Can someone help?
.

```
let slideIndex = 0;

function SlideShow(){
    let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
    for (let i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }

    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(SlideShow, 10000);

} 

SlideShow()
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this here is your mistake:

```js
slideIndex++;
if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
```

if it doesn't find any slide at the beginning of your code it will jump over the for loop. But in this case you would add 1 to slideIndex so it's value will be 1. In this case slideIndex is greater than slides.length (0) and slideIndex will be set to 1. Then you will access slides[1] which is undefined and you want to access style of undefined.

I would recommend you to step over your JavaScript with your Browser to see if your selector gets any elements. With this debugging you should also get the place where you access style of undefined.